# Is there a & (BASH) equivalent for DOS Batch files?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, batch-file, ms-dos

I'm thinking not since that violates the principle of batching.  So what are my options if I want to launch two apps in windows in one script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298562/windows-xp-or-vista-how-can-i-run-a-batch-file-in-the-background-no-windows-dis

In short, "start /b" is the dos solution, but there are a few other options depending on your environment.